# UIDocumentMenuViewController is taking little longer to load for first time

Tags: ios, swift

```
let documentMenuController = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: ["public.data"], in: .import)
        documentMenuController.delegate = self
        documentMenuController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        documentMenuController.addOption(withTitle: "first Item", image: UIImage.init(named: "hey"), order: .first, handler: { _ in
        })
        present(documentMenuController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I am using this code to show the documentmenu is there any way i can show progressbar until it loads.

Comment: may be your data is high

Comment: you shouldn't. Calling the document picker is processed within half a second usually. Your data structure is very likely to be the source behind the delay. Attempt refactoring.